# how to call context menu

Tags: android

I open my context menu like this:

```
 private OnClickListener optionsClickListener = new OnClickListener()
 {
  public void onClick( View v )
  {
    registerForContextMenu( v );
    openContextMenu( v );
  }
 };
```

How can I call

```
registerForContextMenu( v );
openContextMenu( v );
```

from inside my regular menu handler here:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item )
 {
  switch( item.getItemId() )
  {
    case OPTIONS:
      registerForContextMenu( v );
      openContextMenu( v );
      return true;
```

where I have no View to pass?

Comment: Are you trying to show a ContextMenu from an Option Menu item?

Comment: This is entirely possible, it is just that your original question was quite unclear and not understood. I am surprised that no-one answered this later as the comment make what you want quite clear. When people have trouble understanding your question, you should edit it, as well as replying to comments.

Comment: you might want to consider a listed dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Registering a context menu is when you want to allow the user to open it by long clicking. If you want to open it programmatically, you simply have to call [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29). As for obtaining the view, you can either use [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) if you gave it an id or save it as an attribute in your `Activity` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `this` which is also a view.

Comment: In the context I described, "this" is an Activity, not a View.

Comment: What are you doing to the view in these methods?  The view that you're passing in isn't your main view, it's the view that got the event, so the button or whatever.

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected() does not provide access to a View.  It provides access to a MenuItem.  How do I call registerForContextMenu() and openContextMenu() in the context of onOptionsItemSelected() where I only am given a MenuItem, not a View?  How do I get the current View from the MenuItem?  item.what?.what? ?

Comment: Ok, I am completely confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.  From a users standpoint you want them to press the menu button and select the "Options" menu item and that should pop up another menu?  The point of a ContextSensitiveMenu is that it offers options that are specific to whatever it is you clicked on.  They aren't meant to control options for an app.  If that's what you want you should use a custom dialog or a new activity.

Comment: Sorry you're confused, it's really not that hard to understand, I just want to know how to open a context menu from a menu item click. I'm going to assume it can't be done at this point since no one knows how.  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is actually a [submenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), where it allows you to popup a submenu upon clicking on the menu item.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm trying to do at all.

Comment: Any reason you MUST popup a ContextMenu from OptionMenu, rather than showing a sub menu; from the UI and Code perspective, they look almost the same. If you REALLY MUST, you can pass in any View, such as ImageView, TextView, Button, etc.