# Android ListView ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to create a `ContextMenu` when user tap hold on an item in my `ListView`. However my code doesn't show anything when I tap hold on my item. Could somebody please check on my code. Thank you.

```
public class MyD extends SherlockListFragment implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;

    private Fragment mFragment;

    private ListView DLListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.dl_listview);

        View empty = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty);
        DLListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.DLListView);
        DLListView.setEmptyView(empty);

        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Error! No SDCARD Found!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "St");
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        DLListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.DLListView);

        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/St/");

        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            String fileName = list[i].getName();
            fileName = fileName.replace(".txt", "");
            myList.add(fileName);

        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.simplerow, myList);

        DLListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        DLListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String textToPass = myList.get(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewActivity.class);
                textToPass = textToPass.replace(textToPass + "", textToPass
                        + ".txt");
                i.putExtra("textToPass", textToPass);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    DLListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});

}

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
       String name = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
       menu.setHeaderTitle(name);      
       menu.add(0,v.getId(), 0, "Play");    
       menu.add(0,v.getId(),1,"Delete"); 
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean on longclicking?

Comment: yes Appu. Could you help?

Comment: You can use ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(). Did you?

Comment: I just edited my code. How do I link my context menu with the OnItemLongClickListener()?

Comment: @DroidBeginner, Already answered your question. See below if it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DLListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          registerForContextMenu( view );
          openContextMenu( view );        

        return false;
    }
});
```

Even you can use `closeContextMenu()` if you want to close. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I use use the OnItemLongClickListener() and ContextMenu at the same time, that is item long click and context menu appears at different conditiosn?

Comment: Of course as long as you mention conditions in the onItemLongClick(), there is no harm done afaik. But make sure to register for contextmenu only in that condition, not outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean longClick, you're lacking the `OnItemLongClickListener()`.

And, to call the Context menu, check this: [how to call context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942600/how-to-call-context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You must register the ViewGroup (DLListView) to recognize the component in the menu.

```
 DLListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.DLListView);
 registerForContextMenu(DLListView);
```

With these changes is not necessary to register each element in the ListView component.